# Server - clean up tool?

Tags: windows-server-2008, disk-space-utilization

I have a Windows 2008 virtual server. Some how every week my server uses an extra 2 gigs and I do not know the reason.
Are there any free utility tools that can scan a server and let you know whats gobbling up space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info) does a nice job of displaying disk utilization; drilldown into directories organized by size, refresh the whole thing or just a subdirectory after you've done some cleaning. Sorts the "tree" display at the top by cumulative size as it scans; displays the lower graphical representation only after the scan finishes.

Allows you to create user-specified "cleanups" such as compressing an entire directory structure into a 7zip file via command line.

Free, GPL, stable for years. Now on sourceforge: [WinDirStat Project Page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windirstat/)

And if you don't like its default "pacman" animation while it's scanning a directory structure you can turn it off from the options.

Comment: I use WinDirStat and it is very nice.  At first the graphical display seems silly and chaotic, but then you see this one huge square and think "hmmm, i wonder what that huge file is" click on it, and it jumps you right to it in the folder list.

Comment: I also love WinDirStat.  It's very small, which comes in handy when a client site has run out of disk space... I can find a way to get it to fit, or run from another location.

Comment: WinDirStat is great, but you can't run it on server core (requires oledlg.dll which isn't there).  Anyone suggest an alternative that can be run on server core?

Comment: I don't have a server core system on which to try it, but you might check whether the Sysinternals Disk Usage tool (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651) works. It's listed as "Server: [...] 2003 and higher".

Comment: As a further note, WinDirStat isn't really looking at anything disk-specific, just files. That means you should be able to use it to look at an administrative share (e.g. C$) or any other share, though you might need to map to a drive letter.

Answer (score 1):

We use [TreeSize](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml) to do these types of things (although we bought the pro version as well for a few of our servers

Answer (score 1):

I use JDiskReport (free) for this purpose. You can also check the other options [here](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/treesize-free/)

Answer (score 0):

I like [SequoiaView](http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview//) because it groups trees together and you can color different file types to visually see what's taking up space.