# Is there a Windows equivalent to the Unix du command?

Tags: windows, disk-space-utilization

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What are good tools to show disk usage (for Windows)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1687/what-are-good-tools-to-show-disk-usage-for-windows)
>   [How to determine a disk consuming service in Windows 2008 server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/176123/how-to-determine-a-disk-consuming-service-in-windows-2008-server)

I am troubleshooting performance on a PC with (running Windows 7) whose hard disk is almost full.  I am assuming that there is some directory where the user has dumped many large files.  On Unix, I would use the 'du' command to determine which directories contributed most to disk usage.  How do I accomplish this on Windows?  TIA - Frank

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/1687/what-are-good-tools-to-show-disk-usage-for-windows, http://serverfault.com/questions/94757/server-clean-up-tool, http://serverfault.com/questions/176123/how-to-determine-a-disk-consuming-service-in-windows-2008-server

Comment: sorry for the dupe.  thanks all for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: [Scanner](http://steffengerlach.de/freeware/) worked for me.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use something like [**TreeSize Free**](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/) from JAM Software or [**WinDirStat**](http://windirstat.info/) which is open source.

Comment: Du (disk usage) reports the disk space usage for the directory you specify. By default it recurses directories to show the total size of a directory and its subdirectories.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/du

Comment: SpaceSniffer is another good one. It's list WinDirStat but shows the directory names directly on the box representing size, which is quite a bit more useful. http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/

Answer (score 10):

There is the [sysinternals du](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896651) command but you may find something more native like [getfoldersize](http://www.getfoldersize.com/) easier to use.

Comment: +1 for sysinternals. Even if you don't use du, the other commands make this suite invaluable on a Windows system.

Comment: +1 for most exact answer, even if some of the others are easier to use.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for WinDirStat

http://windirstat.info/

Comment: I have used WinDirStat for years, it gives you a good overview in under a minute.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any cli tools for checking disk usage. I usually use [windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) to track down what is using my diskspace.

Answer (score 1):

Just to weigh in on GUI tools, I prefer sunburst-style graphs, like [Scanner2](http://steffengerlach.de/freeware/), to treemaps like WinDirStat; I think they're much easier to read.